# Setting current date for a date input type box in a modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-modal

On my page, I have a form that opens up in modal. It has a couple of fields and date is one of them. I want to set it as default to today's date. My modal can be seen below

```
    <!--main modal-->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header" style ="background-color: #38BFEF;">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title"><center><font color="white">New Food Delivery</font></center></h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">

 <!---inside pop up content start-->
  <form>
  <center>
    <p>
        <label for="Delivery Number">Delivery Number:</label>
        <input type="text" name="delivery_number" id="delNumber" style="width:150px;" autofocus="autofocus">
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="Delivery Date">Delivery Date:</label>
        <input type="date" name="datepicker" style="margin-left:4%;width:150px;" id="datepicker">
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="Supplier">Supplier:</label>
        <input type="text" name="supplier" style="margin-left:10%;width:150px;" id="supplier">
    </p>
     <p>
        <label for="Supplier">Cost of Delivery:</label>
        <input type="text" name="cost" style="margin-left:1%;width:150px;" id="cost">
    </p>
    </center>
    <center><input type="button"  id="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-lg vbtn" value="Submit" onclick="submitDelivery()" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirmModal"></center>
</form>


 <!---inside pop up content end-->
       </div>
        <div class="modal-footer" style ="background-color: #38BFEF;">
          <input type="button" id="close" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" value="Cancel">
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
    </div>
```

Then I have a couple of javascript functions for different things, for example going through the inputs with enter presses, submitting the form when enter is pressed etc.

One of the functions is to set the date for the #datepicker and it looks like this

```
$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
     $('#delNumber').focus();

    var now = new Date();
    var day = ("0" + now.getDate()).slice(-2);
    var month = ("0" + (now.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);

    var today = (day)+"/"+(month)+"/"+ now.getFullYear();
    //alert(today);
    $('#datePicker').val(today);
})
```

However, when I open the modal in Chrome, the box still says dd/mm/yyyy, seems like the function doesn't work properly?

Another issue is that when I open the above code in Firefox, it doesn't seem to recognize the Date box as date input type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In form you have id as *datepicker* and you are trying to access *date**P**icker* (Notice the capital P)using jquery.

Comment: True, I missed that one. I changed it now but it still doesn't seem to be setting the date in Chrome. It seems to work in Firefox but like I said, Firefox doesn't recognize the input type as being date.

Comment: @ArtleMaks ctrl+shift+r (or cmd+shift+r) to refresh the cached js in chrome. jquery should perform equally in both browsers.

Comment: @Iwrestledabearonce. That's what I would've thought but it doesn't seem to be the case. Can you try opening this http://easycount.io/platform/fooddeliveries.php?id=9 in Firefox and Chrome so I can see if it's something on my side maybe?

Comment: I got this reference from W3Schools: Note: <input> elements with type="date" do not show as any date field/calendar in Firefox, or in IE11 and earlier versions.

Comment: @ArtleMaks - confirmed, you're right, works in FF, chrome shows this error: `jquery.min.js.download:4 The specified value "13/01/2017" does not conform to the required format, "yyyy-MM-dd".` try this: `var today =  now.getFullYear()+"-"+(month)+"-"+(day);`

Comment: @Iwrestledabearonce. you're a genius, that did the job. Well, almost. I just had to use var today = now.getFullYear()+"-"+(month)+"-"+(day);
Thanks for both of you for the input and help!

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `DD/MM/YYYY` you need to use format `YYYY-MM-DD`

So resulting string will be:

```
 var today = (now.getFullYear() + '-' + month + '-' + day);
 $('#datepicker').val(today);
```

Here is working example: https://jsfiddle.net/panamaprophet/2Lt2q3ga/